# Some of my asp.net api attribute based routing are returning 404 (not found)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

In the asp.net mvc 5 + web api 2 am working on, some of the webapi routes that I defined are not working, while some are working perfectly. I can't seem to identify what the problem is. And before you ask I have read the whole SO questions and applied all the solutions I can find, but none of it seems to work in my current situation. I also checked, double checked and yet I can't figure out why. Here are some of the configurations and route registrations that I think affects web api.

**Route definition**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("FollowApi/{profileId:int}/FollowClient" Name = "FollowClient")]
```

**Application_start configuration**

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

**Webconfig configuration**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />      
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Please, any help or pointers as to why this problem is occurring will be seriously appreciated as I am in a time constrained situation.

**Edit**

**Working api**

```
public class CommonApiController : BaseApiController
{
   [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Client/GetInfoCounts")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInfoCounts()
    {
      //Method body
    }
}
```

**Not working api**

```
public class FollowApiController : BaseApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
    [Route("FollowApi/{profileId:int}/FollowClient")]
    public IHttpActionResult Follow(int profileId)
    {
      //Method body
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could show the code for the controllers where the route does work, and then code for controllers where they don't.
Also, are all your routes Attribute based, or do you have some of them in configuration?

Comment: Okay let me edit the question.

Comment: Wouldn't make sense to define your route having the parameter as the last token: `[Route("FollowApi/FollowClient/{profileId:int}")]` ?

Comment: @Alexei Why not, the above route says follow client with the profileId

Comment: Have you tried creating a blank web api2 project, and comparing the system.webServer sections? I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve by removing the UrlRoutingModule and ExtensionlessHandler. Also, when you are adding the ExtensionlessHandler, are you sure the syntax for the path="*." is correct?

Comment: Yes, but I found more natural to have the parameters as the last segments of the routes. Also, it might solve the problem :).

Comment: @Martin, I added this tag  `<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />` yersterday when I was researching SO trying to find a solution. It wasn't working before I added it and even after adding it, it made no difference so I just sort of left it there.

Comment: I understand, does copying a "vanilla" web.config solve your routing problem?
Also, are you actually using "POST" to hit the route?

Comment: I have removed the two 'UrlRoutingModule' tag, and copied "vanilla" web.config and yes am hitting the route using jquery post ajax method.

Comment: What is the url you are trying to hit?

Comment: I mean am using jquery post ajax method to hit the url that's not working

Comment: Can you show the request url string you are using please?

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I have resolved the issue. I was using the `RoutePrefix` tag and forgot to add it to the url of the client side. Once again thank you for all the help.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106835/discussion-between-cizaphil-and-martin).

Comment: Can we make an answer out of this? This would be useful for others I think.

Comment: Done. Please accept / upvote , if you think it might be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the RoutePrefix on the controller was not included in the client call. My take away from this is that it makes sense to have a certain pattern for troubleshooting these kind of problems.
Something like:

- Is the url correct?
- Is the httpMethod correct?
- Are the parameters named correctly?